# Two Windows server, not in domain, grant permissions to each other's users

Tags: backup, permissions, windows

We have two Windows Server machines, which are not in domain. Sql Server runs on one of them.
We want to save backups of Sql Server to another server. We created a folder in second server then we gave everyone permission to folder.
When we backup the Sql server, we got an error, Permission denied. I understand the problem but I want to learn giving permission to another server's users for the folder.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a ***minimal understanding of the problem being solved.*** Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/) for further guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only grant permissions to local users if not in a domain, not to users of another system. The other computer than has to connect with the credentials of a user local to the target computer to be able to access it.

Comment: Small exception: you can grant it to guest, but you shouldn't.

Comment: and you can fool it if necessary by creating the same username/password combination on the target server that is currently being used as the login on the "client" server for the sql server service.